# Android : Simple Date Format

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have a problem in date.

For example now is February 4, 2016.

And I am populating(I don't know the exact rem) the textview with the current date(dd) but the result I am getting is February 35 2016.

this is my code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("D");
String cDay = dateFormat1.format(new Date());
Day.setText(cDay);
```

Comment: If all you need is the day, you could use Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D - Day in year` and `d - Day in month`

u can use below-

```
DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
String cDay = dateFormat1.format(new Date());
Day.setText(cDay);
```

Comment: so Captital D and small d is not the same? :3 tss haha I didn't know it XD btw its okay now thanks

Comment: @CallMeJeo: Plz accept it :) Nope dey r not. refer this link - http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
public static String getDateFormat(String date) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String convertedDate = "";
        try {
            Date parseDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            convertedDate = fmtOut.format(parseDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertedDate;
    }
```

OR

```
public static String getTodaysDate() {
        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance(); //Get the current date
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy "); //format it as per your requirement

        return formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy, H:MM a")

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");
String cDay = dateFormat1.format(new Date());
Day.setText(cDay);
```

hope this code will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d").print(DateTime.now());
```

It returns string value